# find difference between two date textboxes

Tags: c#

in my c# form i have two date text boxes on for borrow date and the other for return date

**borrowed_date_txt , return_date_txt**

i  want to compare two text boxes to find difference between them and if the date of
 **borrowed_date_txt** is greater than the date of **return_date_txt** i want to make the **return_date_txt** background red?

Comment: What have you tried. What do you mean by C# Form? Do you mean Web Form? Windows Form? We need more info.

Comment: Please post your code whatever you have tried...........

Comment: Got to love all the hyena' trying to scavenge reputation without knowing WTF the user is asking help for.

Comment: windows forms .... i don't try to wirte any code

Answer (score 2):

Parse them to `DateTime`s and `TimeSpan`s and do your logic/comparisons with these.  Then call `ToString()` in the result and you will get a default-formatted date and time.  `DateTime` also provides very handy properties based on the dates.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx

EDIT: I am assuming this is a Windows Form and not a web form.  I will revise if web is what you need.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DateTime.Compare`

```
int idiff = DateTime.Compare(DateTime.Parse(borrowed_date_txt), DateTime.Parse(return_date_txt));
if (idiff > 0) //borrowed_date_txt is greater than the date of return_date_txt 
{
//Do what you need    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should [convert string to date](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc165448.aspx) 
then you could try this:

```
DateTime date1 = Convert.ToDateTime(borrowed_date_txt);
      DateTime date2 = Convert.ToDateTime(return_date_txt);
      int result = DateTime.Compare(date1, date2);
      string relationship;

      if (result < 0)
         relationship = "is earlier than";
      else if (result == 0)
         relationship = "is the same time as";         
      else
         relationship = "is later than";
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work for you.

```
System.TimeSpan = EndDate.Subtract(StartDate)
```

gives you the difference in days-hours-seconds-milliseconds.  If you just want the difference in the # of days, you can specify that by using the `Days` property of the `System.TimeSpan` class.

```js
DateTime StartDate;
DateTime EndDate;
TimeSpan Difference;

StartDate = Convert.ToDateTime(txtStartDate.Text.ToString());
EndDate = Convert.ToDateTime(txtEndDate.Text.ToString());

Difference = EndDate.Subtract(StartDate);

lblDifference.Text = Convert.ToString(Difference.Days);
```